# Make Sure Outlook Loads All the Plugins

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

My antivirus ( ESET) hanged some days ago, and that brought down its outlook plugin as a result. So when I tried to launch outlook, I would get a message, saying that outlook cannot launch. After I did this a few times, the outlook asked me whether agree to disable all the plugins, which I clicked yes.

The problem now is that after I restart my pc, ESET is working fine, but the Outlook is no longer loading any of my plugins. Is there anyway to tell OUtlook to load the plugins?

Comment: Is this not Tools/Addins from the Outlook menu..?

Comment: There is no Tools/Addins menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

The way to enable all the plugins is go to `Help-> About Microsoft Office Outlook`. Click on `Disabled Items`, and enable everything.